# How to navigate to nth page in pagination using Selenium WebDriver with java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, pagination

Please help me to navigate to the nth page in Selenium WebDriver using java.

I just navigated to https://www.google.co.in/ and searched for a text. Now I want to navigate to nth page(ex:7). How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible:-

What you can do here is for a search result `Google` shows `10` results on a page and every time you click on any of the page it changes the value of `url` parameter `start`.

So what you can do is:-

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
// If you want to navigate to first 2nd page you can append the `start` with some value in the multiple of 10th.
// so for 7th page it would be `start=60`
// for nth page it would be `start = n*10 - 10`
String newURL = url + "&start=" + n*10 - 10
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(newURL);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thankyou. but what i want is 1. Navigate to Google
2. search for a text. Eg: "wikipedia" 3. click on the nth page and select the nth link. and i need to give the value of n in controller.xlsx

Comment: This is how you can do it.. whats the issue here .. you can add the steps for searching the word in google.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by designing the xpath for desired page as given below.

```
public class Pagination {

WebDriver driver; 

 public void f(int x) throws AWTException {

  By search = By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div[2]");
  String l1 = ".//*[@id='nav']/tbody/tr/td[";
  String l2 =  "]/a";
  int n =x+1;
  By page = By.xpath(l1+n+l2);

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ujm0V-2iAeTI8AfvirGgCQ&gws_rd=ssl");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement searchEle = driver.findElement(search);
    searchEle.sendKeys("Selenium");

    Robot rob = new Robot ();
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    driver.findElement(page).click();
  }


 @Test
  public void k() throws AWTException{
  this.f(5);      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the below code:

```
package SamplePrograms;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class NavigateToSearchResults {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_2.22.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("WebDriver");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@value='Search']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='7']")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='resultStats']"))));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Hexdocs')]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.quit();
}

}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

If you need to change the navigation page, just change the number in the `xpath: .//a[text()='7']`